# Toggle Natural scrolling from command line with reload

Tags: macos, system-settings, defaults

I'm looking to make a script that quickly toggles the Natural scrolling settings, so I need a way to do it from the command line.

I think I found the correct defaults command, but I'm not sure how to apply it without logging out. Here is the command I'm using:

`defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences  com.apple.swipescrolldirection -bool`

Answer (score 4):

The same setting is visible in the Magic Mouse and Trackpad panes. This works if you have a Magic Mouse connected (but not if you do not):

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "mouseTab" of pane id "com.apple.preference.mouse"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    click checkbox 1 of window 1
end tell
quit application "System Preferences"'
```

This works if you have a trackpad:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Preferences"
  reveal anchor "trackpadTab" of pane id "com.apple.preference.trackpad"
end tell

tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    click radio button 2 of tab group 1 of window 1
    click checkbox 1 of tab group 1 of window 1
end tell

quit application "System Preferences"'
```

nb: the "Accessibility Inspector" tool that comes with Xcode can be used to locate UI items to click on.