# How to automate changing the settings when you connect the mouse?

Tags: applescript, automator, mouse, automation

I want to change option in System Preferences "Scroll direction: natural" every time I plugin mouse to my MacBook.

And switch back when mouse is disconnected.

This should happen automatically. How it's possible? Automator or applescript?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**Keyboard Maestro**](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/):

[image]

Repeat script with 'is disconnected'.
You may need to change the USB device name.
AppleScript from shell script: [Toggle Natural scrolling from command line with reload](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60877/toggle-natural-scrolling-from-command-line-with-reload)

Comment: Thank you, but Keyboard Maestro is not free software.